Error inserting new Sheet not data is not getting stored
Sub ImportSheetFromAnotherWorkbook2
    ' Declare variables
    Dim oSourceDoc As Object
    Dim oTargetDoc As Object
    Dim oSourceSheet As Object
    Dim oTargetSheet As Object
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim dataArray As Variant

    ' Specify the correct path to the source workbook
    sourceFilePath = "file:///C:/Users/chakri/Desktop/New Folder/SPI.ods" ' Update this path

    ' Load the source workbook
    On Error GoTo LoadError
    oSourceDoc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(sourceFilePath, "_blank", 0, Array())
    
    MsgBox "Source Name: " & oSourceDoc.Title
    
    ' Get the first sheet from the source workbook
    oSourceSheet = oSourceDoc.Sheets(0)

    ' Get the current document (target workbook)
    oTargetDoc = ThisComponent
    MsgBox "Current Workbook Name: " & oTargetDoc.Title

    ' Set the desired name for the new sheet
    newSheetName = "SPI_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS") ' Add a timestamp
    
    ' Insert a new sheet at index 1 (after the first sheet)
    positions = oTargetDoc.Sheets.getCount()
    On Error GoTo SheetError
    oTargetDoc.Sheets.insertNewByName(newSheetName, positions)
    oTargetSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(positions - 1)
    MsgBox "Loaded fine"
    ' Copy data from the source sheet to the target sheet
    dataArray = oSourceSheet.getDataArray() ' Get the data array from the source sheet
    oTargetSheet.setDataArray(dataArray)     ' Set the data in the target sheet
    
    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
    oSourceDoc.close(True)

    MsgBox "Data imported successfully!"

    Exit Sub

LoadError:
    MsgBox "Error loading source document: " & Err & " - " & ErrMsg
    Exit Sub

SheetError:
    MsgBox "Error inserting new sheet: " & Err & " - " & ErrMsg
    If Not IsNull(oSourceDoc) Then oSourceDoc.close(True) ' Ensure source is closed on error
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Hi I wrote The above code to copy and insert data of other sheet and insert to current sheet. But The programs terminates with the error at inserting sheet. The observation is it is inserting a new sheet with the name but it is saying error and not allowing to copy the data.Please can anyone help with this.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Call getDataArray() with a cell range, not a sheet. From 6.23. Searching a Calc document of Andrew's Macro Document:
oCell = oSheet.GetCellbyPosition( 0, 0 )
oCursor = oSheet.createCursorByRange(oCell)
oCursor.GotoEndOfUsedArea(True)
oData = oCursor.getDataArray()

